# Creating a fancy chapter style using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters

Could anyone propose a way to achieve the following chapter style with the given document as a starting point? (The number "1" is the chapter number)

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[paperheight=9.3in,paperwidth=6.85in]{geometry}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{\rule{.7\textwidth}{2pt}}{0pt}
{\hspace*{.3\textwidth}\huge\bfseries}[\addvspace{-1pt}]
\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `explicit` with `titlesec`. This code gives you something very close to your picture.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[paperheight=9.3in,paperwidth=6.85in]{geometry}
\newcommand\myfancychapter{\tikz[baseline=(CHAP.base),very thick]{
  \draw[use as bounding box,draw=white,fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
  \node[fill=white,minimum width=1.5cm,outer sep=0pt,rounded corners] (CHAP) at
  (1cm,\baselineskip+1ex) {\Huge{\textbf{\textsf{\thechapter}}}};
  \draw[draw=gray!30!white,fill=gray!30!white] (2cm,0cm) rectangle (\textwidth,2cm);
  \draw[black, ultra thick](0,1.2cm) -- (\textwidth,1.2cm);
  \draw[black, ultra thick](2cm,0cm) -- (2cm,2cm);
}}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont}{\myfancychapter}{1em}{\LARGE{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I just moved the number below the line because I think this looks better. But with `tikz` you have full control.

EDIT: Here is a ``minimal damage' way of moving the section number above the line. I also had to make the box larger.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[paperheight=9.3in,paperwidth=6.85in]{geometry}
\newcommand\myfancychapter{\tikz[baseline=(CHAP.base),very thick]{
  \draw[use as bounding box,draw=white,fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2.5cm);
  \node[fill=white,minimum width=1.5cm,outer sep=0pt,rounded corners] (CHAP) at
  (1cm,\baselineskip+1ex) {\phantom{\Huge{\textbf{\textsf{\thechapter}}}}};
  \node[fill=white,minimum width=1.5cm,outer sep=0pt,rounded corners] (CHAP2) at
  (1cm,1.8cm) {\Huge{\textbf{\textsf{\thechapter}}}};
  \draw[draw=gray!30!white,fill=gray!30!white] (2cm,0cm) rectangle (\textwidth,2.5cm);
  \draw[black, ultra thick](0,1.2cm) -- (\textwidth,1.2cm);
  \draw[black, ultra thick](2cm,0cm) -- (2cm,2.5cm);
}}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont}{\myfancychapter}{1em}{\LARGE{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

2ND EDIT: Built in @egreg's suggestion. (Grazie!)

Comment: Thank you! How would you go about moving the number above the line?

Comment: I added a minimal damage version. It can be improved, though.

Comment: I usually recommend something like `\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont}{\mychapterheader}{1em}{\LARGE\bfseries}` (no `explicit` option) along with `\newcommand\mychapterheader{<the code for the picture>}`. Cleaner coding.

Comment: @egreg You're right.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a sledgehammer for this: `tabularx`, `booktabs` and `colortbl` will do:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[paperheight=9.3in,paperwidth=6.85in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ >{\filcenter}p{1cm}!{\vrule width 2pt} >{\columncolor{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}[\tabcolsep][0pt]\filcenter}X@{}}\thechapter & \\ \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}&#1\end{tabularx}}[\addvspace{-1pt}]

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]