# Fancy Chapter Style - Custom

Tags: fonts, books

I would like to create a Fancy Chapter Just like the one below:
[image]

Could anyone help me out with this? (With the same Font for the headings and sections)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Just a couple of links to start with: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/403603/231952, https://texample.net/tikz/examples/fancy-chapter-headings/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come somewhat close using the book class. The typesetting program is LuaLaTeX to be able to use the `\fontsize{70}{60}\selectfont`such that the chapter number is larger than `\Huge`. I have created a `tcolorbox` called `titlecolorbox`, which is just a black box with with text. I have used the explicit option for `titlesec` based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165884/217708).  The documentation for the `titlesec` package can be found [here](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), where the `titleformat` function is also explained. I hope this helps.

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{titlecolorbox}[1]{ %the box around chapter
    coltext=white,
    colframe=black,
    colback=black,
    boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    notitle,
    width=4.8em,
    height=2.4ex,
    before=\hfill
}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\sffamily\Huge}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{titlecolorbox}{}
  {\large\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}
  \end{titlecolorbox}
  \vspace*{-4.19ex}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.8em\relax}{\raggedright\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\hfill\fontsize{70}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}
  }
  []

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\sffamily\Huge}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\begin{titlecolorbox}{}
  {\large\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}
  \end{titlecolorbox}
  \vspace*{-4.19ex}\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.8em\relax}{\raggedright\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  }
  []

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\sffamily\large}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\hrule\vspace*{0.25ex}\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{\textcolor{darkgray}{\thesection}\quad\raggedright\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
  [\hrule]

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{10}

\chapter{Modeling Event-Based Behaviour with State Machine}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Overview}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since it works with LuaLaTeX, then, XeLaTeX also can get the compilation done? right? Since, I might have some plans to add some other language texts as well.  Also, I tried Putting up the Table of contents, but that Chapter heading is getting appended to it as well (like the one you showed)  Can that be rectified?

Comment: I guess, we might need to use a titleformat of table of contents as well, since the table of contents is also getting a chapter 0 as a count.

Comment: Yes, also works with XeLaTeX. I have added a numberless version of the chapter titleformat

Comment: i added my problem below @mmencke, could u help me sort it out?

Comment: @Sudarshan see the \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display] I have added to the code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am getting this when I called the \tableofcontents command. I tried using this code below but didn't work:

```
    \titleformat{\tableofcontents}[display]
{\sffamily\Huge}
{}
[]
```