# How to make this header in latex for each chapter

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, chapters

I only work with word at school sadly.

How can I make a chapter heading look like this in LaTeX?

I would like it to be at the very top of the page to save space. For the other pages I am using `\pagestyle{plain}`.

I'm using documentclass `book` & PdfLaTeX.

[image: Ideal Result]

Comment: You can replace \@makechapterhead with pretty much anything, including a tikzpicture.  There are many example here, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403603/creating-a-fancy-chapter-style-using-tikz?r=SearchResults&s=1|61.5171

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are looking for, but you didn't show what you had tried or your documentclass.

```
% chaptitleprob.tex  SE 603312

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%% changes to chapter titles
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-2\baselineskip}  % reduce space above
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1\baselineskip}    % reduce space below
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}            % don't print Chapter
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\scshape\Huge}    % font for the number
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\scshape\Huge}  % font for the title
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\hspace{1em}} % space between number and title

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I leave it up to you to specify the font to be used and whatever shading you need around the number and title text.